New garden bed getting flooded
A month ago I began converting an area that was formerly covered in pavers to a garden bed, but that area is getting flooded. This is what happened when it rained all day yesterday:

The entire area is an in ground compost. The material a couple of inches below the soil consists of leaves and kitchen scraps. Below the leaves and kitchen scrap is rocky dirt. The rest of my backyard is grass and is not collecting water.
What can I do about this flooding? Or is this something I should be worried about, considering that I will turn the soil to (hopefully) expose the compost?

Do you happen to know what is under the leaves and kitchen scraps?  I am wondering if the pavers had a compacted base deeper than the compost layer that isn't letting much water through.  Also, are other areas collecting surface water, or just this bed?

I updated the post. The pavers were sitting on dirt. I removed them, and I all dug up was rocks and dirt.

Looks like the area is trying to drain toward the fence. Remove one of the pavers on that side and see if the water runs off that way.

In general, water is not that mysterious - it will flow to the low point in a landscape. So the shape of the land surface and where the roof runoff is being sent (if this is near a house) are the typical large factors.

If it happens frequently, consider a raised bed.

Can you settle on mint and other moisture lovers?

The water does not move that way if I move the pavers along the fence.

I think your garden bed will be OK. It's possible that the patio had a compacted base that is stopping water drainage, but you've been digging in that bed so I think you would know if that was the case.
Otherwise, I think you have water pooling on top of the clay because the clay isn't very permiable, but once you mix it in with the compost it will drain at least as well as (actually better than) the surrounding soil, which is fine. This is exactly the right situation to compost in ground. Plants will help with infiltration once they start growing too.
If you want to be sure a percolation test is pretty easy to do.

Drainage.
9 times out of ten you likely have compacted or non-soluable soils. LIkely you have clay, a lot of clay, the rocky dirt. The point is, you need adequate drainage, solution is dig up and replace rocky soil underneath and mix it with sand. Basic rule of thumb for soil preparation.

If it's Very clay, Break it up and add sand.
If it's very sandy soil, add compost and some broken clays.

Since it was pavers before they likely added under it's foundation soil matrix to keep water at bay so the pavers wouldn't sink. Your soil is very likely heavily compacted. Ideal garden mix 50% sand, 20-30% compost, rest various load soils you already possess (Broken up)

Lots of misinformation here, especially the "ideal garden mix: (it's not) and the part about adding sand to the (presumably) clay soil. This will create a concrete-like soil, not a freely draining soil. See here for info from an actual scientist: https://extension.illinois.edu/blogs/good-growing/2018-01-31-does-sand-improve-clay-soil-drainage. The best amendments to clay are compost, chopped-up leaves, wood chips and any other organic matter.

My soil is sandy. That's why I was doing the ground compost. I have plenty of leaves. How would I add these leaves to the soil? How deep should I put these leaves?

You shred the leaves and mixthem with the compost.
